# How do I restore files accidentally deleted by the move operation in finder?

Tags: macos, finder, photos, data-recovery

I’m using Mavericks

Suppose we have the folder /a/photos which contains

```
/a/photos/jan
/a/photos/feb
```

And we have /b/photos which contains

```
/b/photos/mar
```

In the command prompt, if we write

```
mv /b/photos /a/photos
```

Then /a/photos will contain all of them (merge):

```
/a/photos/jan
/a/photos/feb
/a/photos/mar
```

However, I did the move operation in Finder (command+c, command+alt+v) and pressed the “overwrite” button thinking it has the same behavior as in mv

Now all my original files in /a/photos are lost. The only thing remaining is:

```
/a/photos/mar
```

How do I recover it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have a recent backup?

Comment: @patrix No. The files are in an external USB hard disk and I don't use time machine or stuffs like that.

Answer (score 1):

**STOP ALL FILE OPERATIONS AND UNMOUNT YOUR HARD DRIVE**

If you haven't written to the Drive since then, it will eventually save you.

When Moving files like this, they get marked as deleted on the drive.
Therefore you can only try to recover them.

Which means:

- Get a Recovery-Software like [DataRescue](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10259/data-rescue)
- Or a free (CLI) programm like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)
- Try recovering the files.